# JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE with unique additions

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a column in a table which is an array of objects. The schema of object is constant.

Like this:

```
col = [{"a": "a_value_1", "b": "b_value_1"}, {"a": "a_value_2", "b": "b_value_2"} ...]
```

Now I want to update the column value by appending new values only if they don't exist in the array already.

I know that updates can be made using `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` but it just appends the value without checking if it already exists. I basically want a json set instead of a json array.

For example

`JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE_VARIATION (col, {"a": "a_value_1", "b": "b_value_1"}) = col`

Does any query like this exist in mysql? Also, we are still on version 5.7

Comment: Make your life easier and DON'T use the JSON datatype.

Comment: Don't really have control over that :/

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. What are you trying to add to the objects in the array?

Comment: Use `JSON_SEARCH()` to test if the object is already in the array. If not, add it.

Comment: Or use a JSON object instead of a JSON array. JSON objects are effectively sets, because the object keys are unique. But you probably will say you don't have any control over that. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(col, '$', JSON_OBJECT('a', 'a_value_3', 'b', 'b_value_3'))
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM JSON_TABLE(col, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        a VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.a',
        b VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.b'
    )) temp
    WHERE temp.a = 'a_value_3' AND temp.b = 'b_value_3'
);
```

Comment: The mysql version is 5.7 as i have mentioned in the post. `JSON_TABLE` is available only after mysql 8